# jQuery Plugin for Google-Plus like Input Field

Tags: jquery, google-plus

I am pretty sure you can help me out! I am very sure that I once saw a jQuery plugin for enhancing input fields like Google Plus uses them:

(Unable to post images yet, maybe someone can edit this? Thanks!)
[Google Plus Input Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7AnP.png)

Sadly, I cannot find it anymore. Does anyone of you know this (or another plugin which does the same)? To be specific, I am looking for a possibility to create a dynamic input field for multiply input values (in one field, see screenshot).

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [jQuery tokenInput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/)

Answer (score 0):

It's called jQuery Autocomplete (multiple).

[Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)

[Here's an online demo](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/)